# Deleting Visual Studio Team Services team project not behaving as expected

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

I have deleted several team projects from Team Services using the Collection Administration Page like this:

[image: collection admin page]
However, the deleted projects still show up in Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio:
[image: Source Control Explorer]
....I expect Source Control Explorer to be a reflection of Team Services.  What am I missing?

Comment: Does it stay there forever or does it disappear from the list eventually? I've just tried your scenario on my account and it works as expected (I can no longer see the project in VS). What version of VS are you using?

Comment: Projects deleted via the top screenshot seem to stay forever.  I have refreshed Source Control Explorer and the Team Explorer Connection in VS several times.  I have also closed and reopened VS a couple times.  The projects still show up in Source Control Explorer in VS.  I am using VS2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Do you still see the project in the browser or is it only VS which has the problem? 
One thing you can try is delete TFS local cache (VS is using it) here: c:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\. It will be regenerated next time you open VS.

Comment: Projects still show in VSOnline|Overview|Recent projects and teams. I now find that clicking on a deleted project on the Recent list returns a 404 error.  I gather that deleting a project via the Collection Administration Page does not automatically delete it from the Recent list, that the project must be manually deleted from the Recent list.  I also gather that the room associated with the project must be manually deleted from the Recent team rooms list.  I would have thought that deleting the project also flushed all its 'stuff'.  Am I beginning to get the picture?

Comment: Also, regarding the local cache, there is a cache folder in a 3.0, 4.0, and 5.0 folder at the path you specified.  The 3.0|Cache folder is empty. 4.0 and 5.0 caches have files.  What specifically needs to be deleted?  Thanks.

Comment: To help others who may follow in my wake: As @JustTFS says below, there are lots of pending adds (see the green plus signs to the right of the folders in the SCE screenshot).  Making matters worse, I had already deleted my local file structure for the projects I was trying to delete from VSO so VSO and SCE and my local files were completely out of whack.  When I undid pending changes for the deleted projects, everything got straightened out.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that screenshot you just need to refresh your workspace. there are a lot of pending adds and the Services project is greyed out meaning that is not mapped.

If you refresh the source tree does the project disappear?

Comment: Please see my answer to OlegM's questions above.  Any further ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh the source control explorer and the server connection in the team explorer. VS will not realize changes in Team Services if you don't ask specifically for it (meaning that changes aren't pushed automatically to the clients).

Comment: Please see my answer to OlegM's questions above.  Any further ideas will be appreciated.